# 'GoogleSignIn' Pod cannot be installed

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am currently trying to install the GoogleSignIn pod to my app. Following the official directions from google, I should put in pod 'GoogleSignIn' to install it, but apparently it doesn't recognise this. I have also used the GoogleMaps and GooglePlaces pods and they have been working fine, so I was wondering what's wrong with the signin pod??

pod 'GoogleSignIn'

[!] Unknown command: `GoogleSignIn`
Did you mean: init?

Comment: `pod 'GoogleSignIn'` is correct. Where are you seeing ` Unknown command: GoogleSignIn` did you run `pod install`? Try `import GoogleSignIn` if that works the pod is correctly installed. If not I'd do a clean and then build again.

Answer (score 2):

From the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating), that line should be in the `Podfile`:

```
Open the Podfile created for your application and add the following:

pod 'GoogleSignIn'
```

As indicated, then run `pod install`